# Codeigniter Delete Linked

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tags and article tables, which are separated. I'm trying to delete the tags which are related to article. When user deletes the article, tags of that article will be deleted from tags table too. I've created the modal below, but this is not working. I didn't get why?

Article Controller

```
public function delete($id){
    $this->article_m->delete($id);
}
```

Article Model

```
public function delete ($id)
{
    // Delete the article
    parent::delete($id);
    // Delete tags
    $this->load->model('tag_m');
    $this->tag_m->delete_article_tags($id);
}
```

Tag Model:

```
public function delete_article_tags($id){
    $this->db->where('content_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('content_type', 'article');
    $tags = $this->db->get('tags');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        parent::delete($tag->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should to delete all dependent information before deleting article. Otherwise it can ruin data consistency.

Comment: Can you show all the code of this models? This line uses parent function delete, but what is the parent of Article Model? parent::delete($id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function delete_article_tags($id){
    $this->db->where('content_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('content_type', 'article');
    $tags = $this->db->get('tags');
    //foreach ($tags as $tag) { <--- Replace this line to:
    foreach($tags->result() as $tag) {
        parent::delete($tag->id);
    }
}
```

Also, check if all models are loaded in the Controller.